# RouteListener returning ROUTING_CANCELLED in some calculations (Here-api)

Tags: android, here-api

Well, my RouteListener sometimes return ROUTING_CANCELLED. I look in documentation and it's says: *"An application user cancelled the calculation."*

**RouteListener**

```
private class RouteListener implements RouteManager.Listener {
// Method defined in Listener
public void onProgress(int percentage) {
    // Display a message indicating calculation progress
}

// Method defined in Listener
public void onCalculateRouteFinished(RouteManager.Error error, List<RouteResult> routeResult) {
    if (error == RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
        // Logic here
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Calc error: " + error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

How to avoid this error? I'm lost x_x ~. Are something in my phone irregular?

Obs: Internet, GPS, battery and cpu are fine.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of how you are triggering the route calculation. Also, any other HERE SDK calls you may be making while the route calculation is ongoing.

Comment: After your comment I saw my code again and realized that I call "new RouteManager()" while the calculation was running. That's it, thanks!

Comment: Glad it was helpful and the problem is fixed!

Comment: Improving my answer:

 - Reverse Geocoding in here maps only work after MapEngine initialization. So, I did not update or instantiating a component during the process, my application was calling the Reverse Geocoding before the MapEngine, triggering this error.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating answer from the comments.

Reverse Geocoding in here maps only work after MapEngine initialization. Calling the Reverse Geocoding before the MapEngine initialization will trigger a ROUTE_CANCELLED error.